# How to differentiate which conference to publish to?

Tags: publications, conference, career-path, early-career

There are many conferences, let's take example cryptography.
I assume it makes a difference if you publish at a good conference
as compared to a bad conference. The question is then: how do I find
good conferences? **How do I guess from web site if it is a good conference.**
For example in cryptography [Asiacrypt](https://asiacrypt.iacr.org/2019/) is one of the best. Let's say level A.
Let's say I want to publish in a lower rank conference say level B, but not level C.

How do I find conferences from level B?

Comment: I don't think this is really something you can discern from looking at the conference's own website, or any other websites.  You need to talk to people that work in the field to see how highly they regard the conference.

Comment: You seem to assume some linear scale. Naive, I think.

Comment: How to gauge at least that the conference is not trash? That is not possible also? To publish at least in a conference where publication will be considered valuable to some degree?

Comment: What does the tag "early-career" mean in this case? Are you a PhD student, a PostDoc, did you just get an assistent professorship? The answer may depend on this.

Comment: I think this is too field-specific for this site.

Comment: @Uwe just an independent researcher

Comment: That's the most difficult case, since there are no advisors or colleagues that you could ask. I'm afraid I can only give heuristics: Assume you know some level A conference in some area. Who are the PC members of that conference (probably some big shots)? Where else do these people serve on the PC? At which conferences do they publish? Which conferences are cited in the proceedings of  the level A conference? As I said, these are only heuristics, but I think they are sufficient to weed out total crap.

Comment: @Uwe Sorry for commenting like this I didn't create an account here. I think you meant level B? Yeah or I could check previous publications from that conference, and see if some moderate level researchers have published there (also heuristics)

Comment: No, I meant Level A. Essentially, the idea is to choose a conference where the top researchers publish their not so strong results, i.e., still a good conference, but not Level A.